# How can I determine whether my iOS device has a torch light?

Tags: iphone, model, capability, avcapturedevice

In my application I have the option for a torch light. Howevver, only iPhone 4 and iPhone 4S have torch lights. Other devices do not have the torch light. How can I find the current device model? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use the device model as an indicator of whether a feature is present. Instead, use the API that tells you exactly if the feature is present.

In your case, you want to use `AVCaptureDevice`'s `-hasTorch` property:

```
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
NSMutableArray *torchDevices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
BOOL hasTorch = NO;

for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
    if ([device hasTorch]) {
        [torchDevices addObject:device];
    }
}

hasTorch = ([torchDevices count] > 0);
```

More information is available in the [AV Foundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW4) and the [AVCaptureDevice Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009520)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Martin Gordon. Your answer working very perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You can have less code and use less memory than the code above:

```
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
BOOL hasTorch = NO;

for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
    if ([device hasTorch]) {
        hasTorch = YES;
        break;
    }
}
```

hasTorch will now contains the correct value

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4

```
var deviceHasTorch: Bool {
    return AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)?.hasTorch == true
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The torch is always attached to the default video capture device, if present.

Answer (score 1):

This code will give your device the ability to turn on the flashlight. But it will also detect if the flashlight is on or off and do the opposite.

```
- (void)torchOnOff: (BOOL) onOff {

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if ([device hasTorch]) {
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchModeOff) {
        device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchModeOn;
        NSLog(@"Torch mode is on.");
    } else {
        device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchModeOff;
        NSLog(@"Torch mode is off.");
    }
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
if let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
    if (device.hasTorch) {
        // Device has torch
    } else {
        // Device does not have torch
    }
} else {
    // Device does not support video type (and so, no torch)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`devicesWithMediaType:` is now deprecated.

Swift 4:

```
let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .back)

for device in discoverySession.devices {
    if device.hasTorch {
        return true
    }
}

return false
```