# Apple binary rejected

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I recently post an app to be reviewed by Apple, but i have been rejected for a second time with this message :

"Binary Rejected

```
2.10: iPhone apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution
```

2.10

We found that your app did not meet the requirements for running on iPad, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.

Your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad."

I don't understand, I found on the internet that I must put only "Iphone" in the summary of my app, and not "universal", but it was already set on Iphone only.
What should I do ?

Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: Does your app run at iPhone resolution when run on an iPad?

Comment: Sorry i only see your message now, the answer is at th next message :)

Comment: What happens when you run your iPhone app on an iPad? Does it crash? What is the error?

Answer (score 2):

You'll first have to figure our why the app does not work on the iPad. Try to run the app in the simulator (for iPad), or even better try to download it on the iPad itself.

Check your info.plist file and see what's there.

Comment: It doesn't work on ipad at first, but when you click on 2x and after 1x, it works. What should i see or correct in the info.plist ?

Comment: In Xcode, go to Project->Build Settings. In the search box, look for Targeted Device Family and make sure it is iPhone. It should update the .plist file

Comment: All is set on iPhone, I don't understand whats the f***

Answer (score 0):

Your application is not compatible to iPad

As per Apple guidelines, every iPhone application must be compatible for iPad too, running with 2x.

Run your application in xcode on iPad simulator or even better test on your iPad device.

Hope this info helps you..

Comment: The problem is it runs, but after click on 2x and 1x, i don't understand why and how can i fix it...

Comment: Was your application initially universal app, Also are you using storyboard in your application?

Comment: No it wasn't universal initially, and i don't use any storyboard. I started to code with an empty app', and don't use any storyboard, all in code. I really don't know how to fix it...

Comment: Yes i'm using the camera, and torch, but i have a test to check if the torch is available. Is there is a link ?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418293/how-can-i-determine-whether-my-ios-device-has-a-torch-light

Comment: Also, try removing that from plist and then try to run your application on iPad. Let me know if that works?

Comment: What should i remove from the plist ? I think the problem is coming form that when i run the application on the ipad simulator, it stops on the menu but no click could be done. You must click on 2x and after 1x to that works perfectly.

Comment: Can you paste screenshot image of your plist. You are making something wrong. The behavior you mentioned is not normal..

Comment: How can i fix it with the .plist please ? :/

Comment: have you added iPad size icons in your icon file? I mean plist here

Comment: It always block with the first clicks on the ipad simulator, really unusual behaviour... !

Comment: Last solution, go to Targets-> click on your target(which will be mostly you app name)->Press delete button. Again create new Target. i hope by this your settings will be updated.

Comment: Please also update me if this helps to solve your issue. i will learn something here..